# What am I missing from my wordpress wp-api test data?

Tags: php, api, wordpress

I am testing out using wp-api, I am very excited to use this by the way. Here is what I have done.

1. installed wp-api and verified that I can get from the website using cURL
2. Installed basic authentication, created an editor level account for this testing.
3. I have tried to update a post using cURL and Postman in chrome.
   my headers:
   -Content-Type: application/javascript
   -data in a file
   I am not sure if there are other headers that I am missing. Both cURL and postman handle username and password in basic authentication for me.

my JSON

```
{  
    "title":"Hello Updated World!",
    "content_raw":"Howdy updated content.",
    "date":"2013-04-01T14:00:00+10:00"
}
```

straight from the examples in [wp-api docs](http://wp-api.org/guides/getting-started.html)

the error I keep getting is

```
[
    {
        "code": "json_missing_callback_param",
        "message": "Missing parameter data"
    }
]
```

Looking at the source code on github it looks like a required parameter is missing

according to the [documentation](http://wp-api.org/#posts_create-a-post_input) title and content raw seem to be the only required fields. I would love to know what I am missing if you have any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the ID which is also required when updating a post. See documentation under 'EDIT A POST': `ID - Unique ID of the post. (integer) required`.

Comment: Same here.  Any luck?

Comment: I have the same error when posting with `multipart/form-data` enctype and a boundary. It works fine without a boundary... Go figure... Free software...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this plugin for making use of Wordpress webservices and by using it you can also create your custom webservice too :

`https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use to call a local WP-API with PHP/cURL:

```
$endpoint = 'http://localhost/my-site/wp-json/wp/posts';
$username = 'test-user';
$password = 'test-pass';

$data = array(
    'title'         => $post_title,
    'content_raw'   => $post_content,
    'status'        => 'publish',
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data),
));

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

To update this post, I would change my data to:

```
$data = array(
    'ID'            => $post_id,
    'title'         => $new_title,
    'content_raw'   => $new_content,
);
```

ID is a required field when updating.