# WordPress API returns status code 400

Tags: android, wordpress, http, wp-api

In my android app i want to display data from WP-API.
I have checked api in browser and it return valid JSON data.
But when i call same api using http request from my android app it return status code 400 with response -

> [{"code":"json_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter data"}]

I have searched but not found any solution.
Please help me how to sort this out.

Thanks in advance.

*EDITED*

Below is my api url - 
http://hostname/feedback/wp-json/posts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282285/what-am-i-missing-from-my-wordpress-wp-api-test-data

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But i did not got what the issue in my request. can you please explain?

Comment: okay .Please use `https` instead of `http` (No enough knowledge on it )

Comment: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: after adding https in request, it returns  - Connection to https://hostname refused

Comment: I assume problem arise from `hostname and port` section

Comment: i think, if hostname is incorrect then it should also return error while calling in web browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95212/discussion-between-ravi-and-intellij-amiya).